# index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2の対処方法

Tags: python, matplotlib, pca

python初心者のものです。
2011枚の画像データを格納しているcsvを読み込み、PCAをかけて結果を前半1000と後半1011に分けてグラフに出力するコードを実行すると

> IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2

と怒られてしまいました。エラーの対処方法をご存じの方はご教授お願い致します。

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

users = np.loadtxt('/home/srl/mimamori1/b1/bb1.csv', delimiter=",")
model = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(users) 


pca = PCA(n_components=2)
users_r = pca.fit_transform(users)
plt.figure()
ccode=[1]*1000+[2]*1011

plt.scatter(users_r[:,1],users_r[:,2],c=ccode)
plt.xlabel('pc1')
plt.ylabel('pc2')


print('各次元の寄与率: {0}'.format(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))
print('累積寄与率: {0}'.format(sum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Pythonのインデックスは(matlabと違って)0始まりなので、

```
users_r[:,1],users_r[:,2]
```

を

```
users_r[:,0],users_r[:,1]
```

に直して見てください。

Comment: 直した所出力ができるようになりました。